# How to add static TableView to ViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

How to add static TableView to ViewController without using of a container and UITableViewController?

I think it was possible some time ago but now with latest xCode storyboard and iOS 7 it is not.
The similar question without valid answer is here - [iOS 7 change UIView to UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19340463/ios-7-change-uiview-to-uitableview)
My table has a little difference - I try to add a static data.
And I get an application crash at program start.
Program crashes if I set just the datasource. If I unlink the datasource and stay the delegate and outlet the program starts without warnings but with empty cells.
A remark - Storyboard changes naming for ViewController from ViewController to TableViewController at view tree without my assistance. I think it occurs after adding an IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView. Why so and what does it mean?

Comment: Do you have any message with the crash ?

Comment: 2013-10-20 13:20:58.154 test[9133:a0b] -[MYTableViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d33300
2013-10-20 13:20:58.160 test[9133:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MYTableViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d33300'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the UITableViewDataSource there are 2 required methods :

```
– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:  required method
– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:  required method
```

It means that in MYTableViewController you must implement those like this (example with 3 cells Test1, Test2 and Test3) :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyStaticCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test%d",indexPath.row+1];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Compilation error - Assignment to readonly property with this string: cell.textLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test%d",indexPath.row+1];
By the way, all this means that I can't use Storyboard to draw cells with children labels, styles, etc. and must do everything programmatically. Am I right?

Comment: textLabel.text (I updated the code). This way is doing it programmatically but you can do it using Storyboard !

Comment: How to do it using Storyboard?

Comment: I have tried:     UITableView *tbv = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myTable01"];
    cell = [tbv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell01"]; But it crashes...

Comment: I have added new TableViewController to the storyboard, added TableView and static cells, set colors and labels. Then I have tried to get access to it:     UITableViewController *tbv = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myTable01"]; [tbv view];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tbv.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell01"]; return cell; But cell = nil! Please help to get access to cells painted using storyboard...

Comment: I have found the mistake. The problem is with the content type of Table View. Error occurs for "Static Cells". For "Dynamic Prototypes" it works without errors. But is it normal behavior? Don't know...